# AWS Step functions map state with activities

Tags: aws-step-functions

It is not clear from the AWS documentation whether dynamic parallelism support with map state in step functions can only be used with lambdas or it can map to activities also as part of nested workflows. Has anybody used this for parallelizing different async activities ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to use any State defined in the Amazon States Language inside a Map State and in case you are wondering you are not limited to a single State, you can define a complete workflow inside the Iterator field of your Map State. Think of it as defining a new State Machine inside your Map State, this is similar to a Parallel State except each branch is the same and the amount of branches is based on your array.

```json
{
  "Comment": "An example of the Amazon States Language using a map state to process elements of an array with a max concurrency of 2.",
  "StartAt": "HardcodedInputsState",
  "States": {
    "HardcodedInputsState": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Result": {
        "array": [
          "Iterate",
          "Over",
          "This",
          "Array"
        ]
      },
      "Next": "Map"
    },
    "Map": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "ItemsPath": "$.array",
      "ResultPath": "$.array",
      "MaxConcurrency": 2,
      "Next": "Final State",
      "Parameters": {
        "Value.$": "$$.Map.Item.Value",
        "Index.$": "$$.Map.Item.Index"
      },
      "Iterator": {
        "StartAt": "You",
        "States": {
          "You": {
            "Type": "Pass",
            "Next": "Can"
          },
          "Can": {
            "Type": "Pass",
            "Next": "Do"
          },
          "Do": {
            "Type": "Pass",
            "Next": "Anything"
          },
          "Anything": {
            "Type": "Pass",
            "End": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Final State": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can I set the value of MaxConcurrency dynamically? Like I have a value for this in InputPath and I want to set the MaxConcurrency to this value.